# change ABPeoplePickerNavigationController properties

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to change some of the properties of the contact table , but i cant .
First i need to remove the cancel button and set an "Add" button instead . i have tried with the delegate method to set it to nil, but it didnt work.

The only way it do work is with this :

```
 [picker setAllowsCancel:NO];
```

which gives a warning that : ( i dont want to take a risk with)

```
instance method not found
```

I also need to remove the "groups" button .

So at the bottom line , i want to remove all the buttons from the upper bar, and set up my own buttons .  how would i do that ?

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Rant,you cann't use method:

```
[picker setAllowsCancel:NO];
```

It's Apple's private APIs(non-public),they'll reject your app.

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *tempABPNC = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
tempABPNC.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
tempABPNC.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:tempABPNC animated:YES];
[tempABPNC release];
```

You must add " tempABPNC.delegate = self; " then implementation UINavigationControllerDelegate method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
viewController.title = @"选择联系人";
tinlnTempVC = viewController;
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
UIViewController *tempABVC = [navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
tempABVC.title = @"选择联系人";
if([viewController.view.subviews count]==0){ //if user disable app open contact,you can create your own view,
    UIView *tempV=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, IS_IPHONE5 ? 504 : 416)];
    ...
    ...
    viewController.view = tempV;
    [tempV release];
}}
```

In this viewcontroller,subclass ABPeoplePickerNavigationController,so we can replace  navigationleft、right、backitem with our own button

```
static UIViewController *tinlnTempVC;
@implementation ABPeoplePickerNavigationController (tinlnCustom)

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 5.0)
    return;
UIButton *dismisBtn = [UIButton DIYNavigationBarItemBtnWithTitle:@"返 回" NC:tinlnTempVC.navigationItem];
[dismisBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backToPayPhone) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];}

- (void)backToPayPhone{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}


@end
```

Hopes help you,Rant,this method in iOS 5.0-6.1 runs perfect, in iOS 4.3-5.0 the backitem cann't replace in the first time show.